# What can i use to make sure nothing is saved on my computer, history,ect

Tags: internet, privacy, privacy-protection

I read a lot of [yaoi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaoi) and i'm looking for a way that no one can trace me back with history or a service provider ratting me out, i'm not sure if incognito is safe enough.

Comment: Even if you manage to keep your own comp clear any data that leaves your computer you have little control over.

Answer (score 1):

Incognito saves the content from appearing in your browser history, but that's not all you have to worry about. All your Internet traffic can appear to your ISP, since they need to route your connection to the servers to get the info. You could try using a proxy, but they would still be able to trace it to you if they had the resources.

As well, if the sites offer extra programs, such as toolbars or other grey-ware programs, they would stay after the Incognito window is closed. If you have viruses on your computer, they can see what you access, and send it back to the virus creator.

So no, it's a step forward, but far from being secure.

Answer (score 1):

If you are really worried with your privacy, you should:

- Use a VPN ([Tunnelbear](http://www.tunnelbear.com/), [HideMyAss](http://www.hidemyass.com/), etc) to access the internet. So nothing that you do can be traced by your service provider. [Tor](http://www.torproject.org) is also good. (unless you do something **really** bad)
- If you are THAT worried with your privacy, you can use a Virtual Machine to do your... 'stuff'. If something goes wrong, you can easy delete it and nothing will be linked to you main OS.

Be safe on your quest.